# How to submit value of inactive tabs Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, bootstrap-tabs

I am submitting dynamic form fields using JQuery Tabs but problem is that it keep submit only last tab values because it check which tab is active and which is not so as it see the last one is active so it posts the value of that tab only not other like 1, 2, 3 etc.

Here is the JQuery code I am using:

```
$('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            var $total = navigation.find('li').length;
            var $current = index + 1;
            var $percent = ($current / $total) * 100;
            $('#rootwizard').find('.bar').css({width: $percent + '%'});
            // If it's the last tab then hide the last button and show the finish instead
            if ($current >= $total) {
                $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').hide();
                $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').show();
                $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').removeClass('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .next').show();
                $('#rootwizard').find('.pager .finish').hide();
            }
        }});
    $('#rootwizard .finish').click(function () {
        alert('Finished!, Starting over!');
        //$('#rootwizard').find("a[href*='tab1']").trigger('click');
        $("#mealForm").submit();
    });
```

**mealForm** is the form id that contains data of all the tabs but only posts last tabs/active tab value not all tabs.

Here is the HTML code with PHP that generates dynamic tabs and dynamic forms but it only submits active tab data not the all ones.

HTML:

```
 <div id="rootwizard">
                <div class="navbar">
                    <div class="navbar-inner">
                        <div class="container">
                            <ul>
                                <?php
                                for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['meal_numbers']; $counter++) {
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a href="#tab<?php echo $counter; ?>" data-toggle="tab">Meal <?php echo $counter; ?></a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
                    <div class="bar"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <?php
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $_POST['meal_numbers']; $counter++) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab<?php echo $counter; ?>">
                            <form action="process/adminProcess.php?page=addClientMealData" method="post" id="mealForm" class="form-horizontal">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <?php
                                    $mealData = 1;
                                    $QuerySet = $objadminViewFunctions->viewAllFoodCategoryData();
                                    while ($RecordSet = $QuerySet->fetch_object()) {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="control-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput"><?php echo $RecordSet->food_name . ' ' . $RecordSet->food_gram . ' (grams)'; ?></label>
                                            <div class="controls">
                                                <?php //print $objadminViewFunctions->viewFoodSourcesDropdownForAddPg($RecordSet->id); ?>
                                                <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[<?php echo $counter; ?>][<?php echo $mealData; ?>][macro_ratio]" type="text">
                                                <input type="hidden" name="mealData[<?php echo $counter; ?>][<?php echo $mealData; ?>][foodCategoryId]" value="<?php echo $RecordSet->id; ?>">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <?php
                                        $mealData++;
                                    }
                                    ?>
                                </fieldset>
                                <ul class="pager wizard">
                                    <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">First</a></li>
                                    <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a></li>
                                    <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Last</a></li>
                                    <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a></li>
                                    <!--<li class="next finish" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:;">Finish</a></li>-->
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next finish" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
                                </ul>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                </div>  
            </div>
```

Here is the output of above HTML form data:

```
<div id="rootwizard">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Meal 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Meal 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="bar" class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
      <form action="process/adminProcess.php?page=addClientMealData" method="post" id="mealForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 60 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][1][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][1][foodCategoryId]" value="37">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 55 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][2][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][2][foodCategoryId]" value="2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 50 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][3][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][3][foodCategoryId]" value="3">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 45 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][4][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][4][foodCategoryId]" value="4">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 40 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][5][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][5][foodCategoryId]" value="5">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 35 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][6][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][6][foodCategoryId]" value="6">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 30 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][7][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][7][foodCategoryId]" value="7">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 25 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][8][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][8][foodCategoryId]" value="8">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 20 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[1][9][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[1][9][foodCategoryId]" value="9">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <ul class="pager wizard">
          <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">First</a></li>
          <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a></li>
          <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Last</a></li>
          <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a></li>
          <!--<li class="next finish" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:;">Finish</a></li>-->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next finish" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      <form action="process/adminProcess.php?page=addClientMealData" method="post" id="mealForm" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 60 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][1][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][1][foodCategoryId]" value="37">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 55 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][2][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][2][foodCategoryId]" value="2">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 50 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][3][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][3][foodCategoryId]" value="3">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 45 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][4][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][4][foodCategoryId]" value="4">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 40 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][5][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][5][foodCategoryId]" value="5">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 35 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][6][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][6][foodCategoryId]" value="6">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 30 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][7][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][7][foodCategoryId]" value="7">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 25 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][8][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][8][foodCategoryId]" value="8">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Protein 20 (grams)</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <input class="input-xlarge focused" id="focusedInput" name="mealData[2][9][macro_ratio]" type="text">
              <input type="hidden" name="mealData[2][9][foodCategoryId]" value="9">
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
        <ul class="pager wizard">
          <li class="previous first" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">First</a></li>
          <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Previous</a></li>
          <li class="next last" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Last</a></li>
          <li class="next"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Next</a></li>
          <!--<li class="next finish" style="display:none;"><a href="javascript:;">Finish</a></li>-->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary next finish" style="display:none;">Submit</button>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Screenshots as per above HTML:

Tab 1

[image: Tab 1]

Tab 2

[image: Tab 2]

Comment: open the form before and close the form after the bootstrap-tabs div

Comment: So that will submit all the tabs data in one go? can you provide any example?

Comment: Yes it will work. I use this. How did you set up the form. Show the HTML code

Comment: I have added HTML and dynamic html for forms as well. please review.

Comment: You are using each tab as separate form. That is why you can submit only one tab. Use only one form which is opened before and closed after bootstrap tabs.

Comment: Great... It is solved now. Can you post it as answer so I can happily accept  your answer and award you some reps. ;) please post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using each tab as separate form. That is why you can submit only one tab. Use only one form which is opened before and closed after bootstrap tabs

```
<form action="process/adminProcess.php?page=addClientMealData" method="post" id="mealForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="tab-content">
      .....
    </div>
</form>
```